# why netstat shows a digit as a program name for established ssh connections?

Tags: ssh, openssh, netstat

When I run `netstat -antplu`, I see entries like below, where a digit is shown for "Program name". These entries are related to established ssh connections. But why does it show a digit as the program name instead of showing sshd as the process name?

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address   Foreign Address   State         PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 10.1.2.3:43638  5.6.8.7:22        ESTABLISHED   20448/0
```

Update:
the netstat command was executed using the root user. Above output supposed to link to a user who has sshed to this server and then initiate another ssh connection from this machine to a different server.

Comment: "instead of showing `sshd`" – The *foreign* port is `22`, so locally I would expect `ssh` rather than `sshd` (although I can imagine a scenario where `sshd` does it). Investigate what PID 20448 really is (`ls -l /proc/20448/exe` if available; and/or `ps` with various options etc.).

Comment: What user is running `netstat -antplu`?

Comment: the netstat command was executed using the root user.  Above output supposed to link to a user who has sshed to this server and then initiate another ssh connection from this machine to a different server.

Comment: what does `ps u -p 20448` show? and/or `ps ho comm 20448` and/or `ps ho cmd 20448`. (edit and add output to your question, not in a comment).  It looks like that process has set it's name to `0`.

Comment: "a user who […] initiate another ssh connection from this machine to a different server" – Maybe the user did `bash -c 'exec -a 0 ssh 5.6.8.7'`. One can set any name this way. See `help exec` in Bash.